# ComboBox Whith a TreeView

Tags: wpf, user-controls, combobox

I need to create a userControl like a Combobox.
In the items in need a TreeView and a Button.
If I navigate the Tree the Item should go to the Text Box in the Bottom.
If I click the Button the Tree should Collapsed.
My First idea was like This but it isn't good.

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Adresse, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="50" MinWidth="170" Grid.Row="5" Margin="5,2,5,2"/>
            <Button  Width="25" Margin="2"  Click="Down">
                <Image Source="/C1_net;component/Images/arrow.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </Button>               

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Tree"  Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Collapsed">                
            <sdk:TreeView Height="200" Name="treeView1" Width="200" />
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=ApplicationStrings.OKButton, Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}}" Width="75" Margin="5" Click="OnOk" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

If I switch to Visible the Control needs more space.
So I need to bring the Tree in Front of the Rest of the Window.
Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like a very hard-to-use control!

Comment: Make the TreeView a separate Page.  Your question is unclear.  There is no TextBox in the Bottom - only the top and why is Bottom capital.  There are two buttons but you only refer to 1. If you expect help you need to put more effort into your question.

Comment: What's the use case for such a control? I think you should revisit your interaction. I don't understand why you'd want to design form controls like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

> I think you should revisit your interaction.

my problemm wase to think if i select i Item, The Tree wood be closed.
I will navigate in a Hirarchical DataObjekt and Put the Path as selectet Item.
So now I will to somting like this:

```
public interface ITreeViewItemModel
{
    string SelectedValuePath { get; }

    bool IsExpanded { get; set; }

    bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<ITreeViewItemModel> GetHierarchy();
    IEnumerable<string> GetDisplayHierarchy();
    IEnumerable<ITreeViewItemModel> GetChildren();
}
```

and.

```
public class ComboBoxTreeView : ComboBox
{
    private ExtendedTreeView _treeView;
    private ContentPresenter _contentPresenter;

    public ComboBoxTreeView()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ComboBoxTreeView);
    }
```

......

I found This http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/silverlight-combobox-with-treeview-inside/